Unable to use a .jar with a .desktop entry file
I want to set up a .desktop entry file to run a .jar as a regular program which can be started in the App-Menu.
I made a directory named Mars4_5 with the following content:
├── Mars4_5.desktop
├── Mars4_5.jar
└── mars.png

The Mars4_5.desktop file looks like this:
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name= Mars4_5
Comment=mars4_5 MIPS32-architecture assembly simulation
Exec=java -jar /home/USERNAME/.local/share/applications/Mars4_5/Mars4_5.desktop
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=/home/USERNAME/.local/share/applications/Mars4_5/mars.png

However after rebooting, I can't see the icon in the App-Menu.
What am I doing wrong?
I previously used a similar file setup with a .desktop entry file for an .AppImage, which worked.
EDIT
I followed the comment by @steeldriver and moved it into /home/USERNAME/.local/share/applications/.
After rebooting, I can see the icon in the App-Menu but it will not start by klicking  on it. What could be the reason for that?

AFAIK personal .desktop files need to go in ~/.local/share/applications unless you added the directory to your XDG_DATA_DIRS - see for example How to add a folder with .desktop files?

Your Exec line looks incorrect. You don't run the .desktop file. You run the .jar file.

.desktop files are executed in a ddifferent context. Your environment variables ($PATH, etc) are not passed through. Try using the full path for java (type -p java), then worry about the rest of your environment (env | sort to start).
